# Promise not returning value of request

Tags: javascript, promise, request, tampermonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest

I have this promise:

```
function getAPI(token)
{
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Request API");
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: "URL"+token,
        onload: function(response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
            if( response.responseText == "NOT_ANSWER" || response.responseText.indexOf("ERRO") > -1 ){
                console.log(response.responseText + " - Calling Myself in 5 Seconds");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    getAPI(token);
                },5000);
            }
            else{
                console.log('Call API - Giving Result');
                resolve(response.responseText.split("_")[1]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

}

I call it inside of itself when the answer is not what I want, cannot be less than 5 seconds though.

Then I do this in the main function:

```
setTimeout( function(){
                getAPI(token).then((key) => {
                    console.log(key);
                    doSomethingWithKey;
                    setTimeout( function(){
                        loop();
                    },1000);
                }).catch(() => {
                    console.log('Error na api - reload page!');
                    location.reload();
                });
            },25000);
```

But I noticed that when getAPI calls itself cause answer is not what i want, the '.then' in the main function never executes and my code hangs there. How can I fix it? I don't understand much of promises but I can't see why it hangs ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I call it inside of itself when the answer is not what i want,

and then you don't call `resolve` of the promise which you had returned from the top `getAPI` call, so the promise never settles and your `then` callback never gets any result.

You should [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) your asynchronous functions `GM_xmlhttpRequest` and `setTimeout` on the lowest level, and then only chain your promises. By `return`ing the result of the recursive call from a `then` callback, the resulting promise will resolve with the same result:

```
function xhrAsync(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        GM_xmlhttpRequest({
            method: "GET",
            url: url,
            onload: resolve
        });
    });
}
function delayAsync(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, time);
    });
}
function getAPI(token) {
    console.log("Request API");
    return xhrAsync("URL"+token).then(response => {
//  ^^^^^^                       ^^^^
        console.log(response.responseText);
        if (response.responseText == "NOT_ANSWER" || response.responseText.includes("ERRO")) {
            console.log(response.responseText + " - Calling Myself in 5 Seconds");
            return delayAsync(5000).then(() => {
//          ^^^^^^                  ^^^^
                return getAPI(token);
//              ^^^^^^
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Call API - Giving Result');
            return response.responseText.split("_")[1];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I assume your answer you would work too, although the other one was easier for me to implement.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit more to change but a cleaner and safer solution. By using promises everywhere, you get their benefits such as error recovery etc. If you like it, you can still upvote it while accepting the other answer :-)

Comment: I actually had to use your soluction and it worked better.
One question though. Lets say i have a timeout set before doing this calls and suddenly i go that timeout and i want to cancel all timeouts and calls being done here. Calling the "first" timeout in my function where getAPI is called will also cancel all timeouts inside or no?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating multiple promises, because each call to `getAPI` creates and returns a *new* promise.

`getAPI` shouldn't call itself (or if it does, it should pass the new promise into `resolve`); instead, just retry the part within it you need to retry, something along these lines:

```
function getAPI(token) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Function to do the request
        function doRequest() {
            console.log("Request API");
            GM_xmlhttpRequest({
                method: "GET",
                url: "URL" + token,
                onload: function(response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                    if (response.responseText == "NOT_ANSWER" || response.responseText.indexOf("ERRO") > -1) {
                        // Not what we wanted, retry
                        console.log(response.responseText + " - Calling Myself in 5 Seconds");
                        setTimeout(doRequest, 5000);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Call API - Giving Result');
                        resolve(response.responseText.split("_")[1]);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        doRequest();
    });
}
```

---

Side note: Your code using `getAPI` is checking for promise rejection, but nothing in `getAPI` ever rejects the promise.

Comment: I will try. Indeed you are right i still need to figure what to catch there cause when i get what i DONT want i want to call it again, i will just remove the catch tbh. I see now what you mean, i needed to resolve the new getAPI call so when i get the correct answer it will recursively send the resolve to every promise created "backwards" and finaly give me the result i want. right ?

Comment: Btw, it's 'setTimeout(doRequest, 5000);' or 'setTimeout( function(){ doRequest }, 5000);' ? when i use the first case sometimes it get strange behaviours...

Comment: worked. 

Thank you very much _O_ i wasnt figuring it out

Comment: @PedroOliveira: The issues you've had with `setTimeout(doRequest, ...)` vs. `setTimeout(function() { doRequest(); }, ...)` probably relate to `this` within the call (which isn't relevant to `doReques`) or arguments passed to the function. E.g., there's a big difference between `setTimeout(obj.method, 5000);` and `setTimeout(function() { obj.method(); }, 5000);`, more [in this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).